# How to set start time of user status via API?

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

We are trying to set the user status through an api, and sometimes it is required to set the status for tomorrow. I have seen that the profile field doesn't have a start time in users.profile.set method. Do you guys have any suggestions. It would be great help.

```
POST /api/users.profile.set
Host: slack.com
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Bearer xoxp_secret_token
{
    "profile": {
        "status_text": "riding a train",
        "status_emoji": ":mountain_railway:",
        "status_expiration": 1532627506
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no option in the API to make a new status for a user appear in the future. You can only set an expiration date.

To get that functionality you need to develop it yourself with a Slack app and some scheduling mechanism, e.g. CRON.

Here is a basic outline how that app could work:

1. Slack app

   - Custom slash command to set a scheduled status for a user
   - App stores future date of status for user in own database
2. Batch

   - Is triggered on a regular basis (e.g. every minute) to check for status to update (e.g. by a CRON job / Web CRON scheduler)
   - Checks if there are any current status updates to post
   - If yes: Posts new status updates and marks them as posted / deletes them in their database